# Question about remainder in automata construction that checks divisibility

Tags: finite-automata

I'm trying to understand de construction of a DFA from the book "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation by John Hopcroft and Jeffrey Ullman 1st ed"
It says:
[image]

Where it says "If the remainder of i/3 is p, then the remainder of 2i/3 is 2p mod 3." its dividing it twice to get the remainder. Shouldn't it be done only once? And why when describing the case for `(2i+1)/3` don't they use `p`?

I've seen other questions about this same automata in SO but they use a less mathematical explanation to how to build it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question: "Why $i/3 \equiv_3 p $ implies $2i/3 \equiv_3 2p$?

If so, the premise means that $i/3 = 3k + p$ for some integer $k$. Now, $2i/3 = 2 \cdot 3k + 2p = 3 \cdot (2k) + 2p$, so if you take $k' = 2k$ you have that $2i/3 = 3k' + 2p$, which is exactly the definition of $2i/3 \equiv_3  2p$.

Comment: Yes it is. I was thinking in modulus operation not congruence.
But how can we get the remainder of `(2i+1)/3`

Comment: I think this is wrong in your answer
$i/3 = 3k + p$
Shouldn't it be

$i/3 \implies i = 3k + p$ for some integer k.

And then
$2i = 2 \cdot 3k + 2p = 3 \cdot (2k) + 2p$ taking $k′=2k$ you have that $2i/3=3k′+2p$  

Which is $2i/3 \equiv_3  2p$

And then you can also do $(2i+1)/3$ as:

$2i + 1 = 2 \cdot 3k + 2p + 1 = 3 \cdot (2k) + 2p + 1$ taking $k′=2k$ you have that $(2i+1)/3=3k′+2p+1$

Which is $(2i+1)/3 \equiv_3  2p+1$

If I'm not mistaken